# How to integrate hibernate with spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am newbie in spring. using spring 3.0 mvc. I am creating a spring application, I have a login form,Any one please suggest how to integrate hibernate and its set up...

Answer (score 1):

You can define Hibernate's Session Factory bean in Spring's application context of your application. Look at this example:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
     <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
          <value>dao/hibernate/Login.hbm.xml</value>
       </list>
     </property>
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
     </property>
</bean>
```

where:

**dataSource** - reference to some implementation of javax.sql.DataSource

**mappingResources** - list of Hibernate ORM mapping files (shoul be on the classpath)

**hibernateProperties** - some basic set of Hibernate properties, you should tell Hiberante at least what type of DB you are using

Then you can wire this bean into DAO classes of your application and perform CRUD operations using wired sessionFactory object.

Suggestion for the future: you should be more specific in your questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Springfuse](http://www.springfuse.com/). It's a tool which build a maven projet with Spring, Spring-mvc and Hibernate. It can provides you some demos (very usefull for newbies).

Answer (score 0):

Not really a tutorial but, for an overview of the Spring 3.0 web stack, I'd recommend... [Overview of the Spring 3.0 Web Stack](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/donald-overview-spring-3.0-web-stack).

In this presentation from SpringOne 2009, Keith Donald discusses the Spring 3.0 web stack, key Spring Framework and Spring MVC features, demos of Spring MVC capabilities, REST support, validation support, automatic data conversion, data binding and validation, Joda Time support, Spring JavaScript, Dojo, Spring Web Flow, Spring Security, Spring BlazeDS, and the roadmap for the Spring web stack.

For the persistence, maybe have a look at JPA 2.0 and Spring 3.0 with Maven. But the documentation is still the best resource IMO. See the 13. ["Object Relational Mapping (ORM) Data Access"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

Regarding the IDE, [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) will indeed give you the best user experience

For example, refer below links:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html